# having an if statement inside a loop without calling it in each iteration

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, foreach

I have the following code:

```
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
    if (args.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("Please provide a correct directory path as an argument!");

    } else {

        System.out.println("Thanks for using our CodeMetrics\n"
                + "The process Might take a long time, please wait!\n"
                + "Please check the CSV file for the final results!");
        File ad = new File(args[0]);
        File[] list = ad.listFiles();

        for (File f : list) {

            CodeMetrics codeMetrics = new CodeMetrics();

            codeMetrics.parseCommandLine(f.toString());
            codeMetrics.countComplexity(codeMetrics.sourceCodeFile);

            // Count LOC (Lines of Code)
            codeMetrics.countLines(codeMetrics.sourceCodeFile);
            codeMetrics.countTestLines(codeMetrics.testFiles);

            codeMetrics.printReport();
            codeMetrics.writeReport();

        }

    }

}
```

right now I would like to give the user the opprtunity to choose wither to call `printReport()` method or to call `printReport()` and `writeReport()` together. The problem is if i put an if statement it will be inside the for each loop and the user will have to choose for each iteration in the loop.
The only idea that I can see is to implement to different methods as the following:

```
    public static void onlyPrint(final String args){

}

public static void printAndWrit (final String args){

}
```

and both methods will have the same code, except that one of them will have printReport() and the other will have both methods. But I'm not really satisfied with that solution as I believe it will have much of code redudancy! Is there a better solution?

Thanks

Comment: Another way of wording this is to give the user the opportunity to write the report or to not write the report. In both cases print will be called.

Comment: Ask the user before the loop, and use a boolean value for whether they want one method or both. Then use that value in an if statement in the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What [Drew Kennedy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4204026/drew-kennedy) said is most likely the easiest answer to implement.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
if (args.length == 0) {
    System.out.println("Please provide a correct directory path as an argument!");

} else {

    System.out.println("Thanks for using our CodeMetrics\n"
            + "The process Might take a long time, please wait!\n"
            + "Please check the CSV file for the final results!");
    File ad = new File(args[0]);
    File[] list = ad.listFiles();

   //ask the user here
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("Please enter a number : Would you like to (1) print, or (2) print & write?");
   int answer = scan.nextInt();
   boolean write = false;
   if (answer == 2) {
      write = true;
   }

    for (File f : list) {

        CodeMetrics codeMetrics = new CodeMetrics();

        codeMetrics.parseCommandLine(f.toString());
        codeMetrics.countComplexity(codeMetrics.sourceCodeFile);

        // Count LOC (Lines of Code)
        codeMetrics.countLines(codeMetrics.sourceCodeFile);
        codeMetrics.countTestLines(codeMetrics.testFiles);

        //check whether the user wants to write or not
        if (write == false) {
            codeMetrics.printReport();
        } else {
            codeMetrics.printReport();
            codeMetrics.writeReport();
        }
    }

}
```

}

This should just ask the user once, and do what you need to get done.

Answer (score 2):

i agree with Childishforlife that the solution with the boolean is the easiest way. I just want to mention a little optimization.

You can turn

```
 //check whether the user wants to write or not
    if (write == false) {
        codeMetrics.printReport();
    } else {
        codeMetrics.printReport();
        codeMetrics.writeReport();
    }
```

into:

```
    codeMetrics.printReport();
    if (write) {
        codeMetrics.writeReport();
    }
```

if i understood everything right the report can be printed in both situations. Only the writing depends on the choice of the user.

Comment: Very true! This is a better coding style then what I had, mine is a little redundant.